# List<T> as 'out' parameter causes an error. Why?

Tags: c#, list, out-parameters

In this code:

```
public bool SomeMethod(out List<Task> tasks)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start(info));
    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

I get an error, *"Use of unassigned out parameter 'tasks'"*. Why?

In an MSDN example there's just use of `out` parameter

```
class OutExample
{
    static void Method(out int i)
    {
        i = 44;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int value;
        Method(out value);
        // value is now 44
    }
}
```

Is it because of `List<T>`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to initialize the `out` parameter in the method body (that is create a new `List<Task>` instance and assign it to the `out` parameter):

```
public bool SomeMethod(out List<Task> tasks) {
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start(info);
  tasks = new List<Task>() { task };
  ...
}
```

I'm using the collection initializer syntax to add the task to the list, but you could call the `Add` method instead if you prefer.

You should call the method like this:

```
List<Task> tasks;
SomeMethod(out tasks);
var newTask = tasks[0]; // Access the task just created.
```

C# 7.0 has introduced new simpler syntax where you declare the variable in the call to the function with the `out` parameter:

```
SomeMethod(out var tasks);
var newTask = tasks[0]; // Access the task just created.
```

As a `List<T>` is passed by reference you can get rid of the `out` parameter. You then have to create the list before calling the method:

```
public bool SomeMethod(List<Task> tasks) {
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start(info);
  tasks.Add(task);
  ...
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
SomeMethod(tasks);
var newTask = tasks[0]; // Access the task just created.
```

In general it is good practice to avoid `out` parameters because they can be confusing.

Comment: And after exiting SomeMethod original 'tasks' will have items from this SomeMethod? I ask because there are many threads in this moment, not all working properly so I can not verify it

Comment: I can't pass by value because I need to pick up all the 'task' at a higher class

Comment: There's no such thing as passing `List<T>` by value. It's a reference type, not a value type.

Answer (score 5):

`out` means that your method needs to create the object, then assign it to the parameter:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(task);
```

Comment: Isn't declaring it enough? (Given that you'll initialize it in the method.) e.g. `List<Task> myTask = null;`

Comment: Setting `tasks = null;` would remove the compiler error regarding the initialization, but you'd get a runtime error on `tasks.Add(task);`

Comment: No, you need to set it. That's what `out` means.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `tasks = new List<Task>();` before you can add a Task object to it. MSDN [has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that is closer to what you're doing, this passes an array rather than an int.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you didn't assign a value to the `tasks`-variable... in this case that would be a reference to a instance of type `List<Task>`.

Add `tasks = new List<Task>();` to the body of SomeMethod and everything will work fine:

```
public bool SomeMethod(out List<Task> tasks) {
   tasks = new List<Task>();
   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process.Start(info);
   tasks.Add(task);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialise the `tasks` parameter. e.g. `tasks = new List<Task>()`

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683394/using-ref-out-keywords-with-passing-by-reference-passing-by-value-in-c) discusses the use of `out` and `ref` with parameters. If you use the `ref` keyword then you must have set the value prior to calling the method.  I see no reason to use the `ref` keyword in this case though